# While Downloading SSRS report as PDF(on button click) in Dynamics 365 ,content is not retrieved

Tags: javascript, pdf, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I want to download a report as PDF on button click. But when i debug my code. the contents of the report are not retrieved. I just get an HTML file

My Code:

```js
callingMethod = function () {
debugger;
var params = getReportingSession();
var newpth = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=" + params[0] + "&Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=" + params[1] + "&OpType=Export&FileName=" + reportName + "&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=PDF";
window.open(newpth, "_self");
}
getReportingSession = function () {
var selectedIds = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var reportName = "AccountOverview.rdl";
var reportGuid = "2b2a692e-7d04-e711-80e6-00155db8652a";
var pth = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/crmeports/viewer/viewer.aspx";
var retrieveEntityReq = new XMLHttpRequest;
var fetchXML = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>< entity name= 'account' > <all-attributes/><filter type='and'><condition attribute='accountid' operator='eq' value='" + selectedIds + "' /></filter></entity ></fetch >";
retrieveEntityReq.open("POST", pth, false);
retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
retrieveEntityReq.send("id=%7B" + reportGuid + "%7D&uniquename=" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName() + "&iscustomreport=true&reportnameonsrs=&reportName=" + reportName + "&isScheduledReport=false&p:CRM_AccountID=" + fetchXML);

var x = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.lastIndexOf("ReportSession=");
var y = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.lastIndexOf("ControlID=");
var ret = new Array();
ret[0] = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.substr(x + 14, 24);
ret[1] = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.substr(x + 10, 32);
return ret;
}
```

#### Screenshot while debugging the code

[image: Screenshot while debugging the code]

Answer (score 0):

In var newpth, set `"ContentDisposition=AlwaysInline"`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes and it's working for me In this I've created a button on Quote by giving "PrimaryControl" and then it's running on the below js. Just change your parameter, Guid, and your file name and it will run.

```
  function runReportToPrint (primarycontrol) {

  var formcontext = primarycontrol;

  var selectedIds = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

  var selectedIds = selectedIds.replace('{', ' ');

  var selectedIds = selectedIds.replace('}', ' ');  

  var reportName = "Task report.rdl"; //change this

  var reportGuid = "54a2f608-b211-ee11-8f6e-6045bdac4f7b"; //change this

  var pth = formcontext.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/crmeports/viewer/viewer.aspx";

  var retrieveEntityReq = new XMLHttpRequest;

  var fetchXML = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>< entity name= 'quote' > <all-attributes/><filter type='and'><condition attribute='quoteid' operator='eq' value='" + selectedIds + "' /></filter></entity ></fetch >";

  retrieveEntityReq.open("POST", pth, false);

  retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");

  retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  retrieveEntityReq.send("id=%7B" + reportGuid + "%7D&uniquename=" + formcontext.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName() + "&iscustomreport=true&reportnameonsrs=&reportName=" + reportName + "&isScheduledReport=false&p:CRM_quote=" + fetchXML);

  var x = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.lastIndexOf("ReportSession=");

  var y = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.lastIndexOf("ControlID=");

  var ret = new Array();

  ret[0] = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.substr(x + 14, 24);

  ret[1] = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.substr(x + 10, 32);

  params = ret;

  var newpth = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=" + params[0] + "&Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=" + params[1] + "&OpType=Export&FileName=" + reportName + "&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=PDF";

  window.open(newpth, "_self");

  }
```